# How to force browser to execute relaced html content in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I produce component in server and ask for content via AJAX. Component is build with mixed HTML/JavaScript. When i cache content with listener function i swap  content(`jQuery#append` function) in div where component will be placed. My question: is there any way to force browser to execute JavaScript in paste `<script>` tags. I found solutions like create `<script>` container with `createElement`. I have many sections with javaScript code in component and only solution is to cut JavaScript from inside and execute (with `eval` function or `createElement`). I'am looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: No, you must extract the script elements and execute them separately, .innerHTML will not execute them. Some jquery methods might do this for you automagically, but not without their own issues (such as timing of when said code gets executed vs when the elements get added to the dom). Try `.html`, but don't' be surprised when you run into more problems due to it. Better to just avoid this issue all together and not have javascript in said html.

Comment: @KevinB Thank You for replay. I have one more question. Is there any lib/method to extract pure script from dom block or i have to do this manually?